# passing using the same uri paramater, getting two different outcomes

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am trying to get a list of 100 help desk tickets from an API. the url is below.

```
https://sdpondemand.manageengine.com/app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={"list_Info":{"row_count":100,"start_index":101}}
```

I am able to produce successful results, meaning it brings back 100 rows starting at index 101, when I put the uri into a string like this:

```
string extra = "app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={\"list_info\":{\"row_count\":100,\"start_index\":101}}";
```

but if I try to put the json into classes, then serialize it with the Json.Net library, it will fail, meaning it brings back just 10 rows on index 1.

```
private class input_data
{
    public list_info list_Info = new list_info();
}
private class list_info
{
    public int row_count = 100;
    public int start_index = 101;
}

input_data input = new input_data();
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
string extra1 ="app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data="+json;
```

I look at both of the request coming out an there exactly the same. what am I doing wrong?

what the vars look like in the code

```
extra: app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={"list_info":{"row_count":100,"start_index":101}}
extra1: app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={"list_Info":{"row_count":100,"start_index":101}}
```

Comment: why are you passing the class object in the querystring? This is the worst implementation of get request according to the documentation.

Comment: then how does one correctly do it?

Comment: is this api implemented by you?

Comment: no, I am following the manage engines API https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/sdpod-v3-api/SDPOD-V3-API.html#list-info

Comment: please see the documentation input_data is supposed to in a post or put request, you need to change the calling

Comment: please check the edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing serialized DTO object in the Get request is not the proper way of implementing an API. Get request supposed to be having params rather than a serialize object. If you wish to do so and have to send an object then why not using a post request.

The sample implementation for a rest api could be as:

**Via GET**

```
[Route("{rowCount}/{startIndex}"), HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int rowCount, int startIndex)
{
     //Your logic Implementation
}
```

calling would be like

```
www.xyz.com/controllerName/100/101
```

This is the rest implementation of the request

**Via POST**

```
[Route(""), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]YourDTOClass obj)
{
     //Your logic Implementation
}
```

For example you have the DTO class

```
//In C# the class name should be capital
private class ListInfo
{
    //In c# the property name should be Capital
    public int RowCount {get; set;} = 100;    
    public int StartIndex {get; set;}= 101;
}
```

So your Post method would look like

```
//Route attribute is for configuring the custom route 
//It is a feature in MVC 5
//FromBody attribute will search for data in the request body
[Route(""), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]ListInfo info)
{
     //Your logic Implementation
}
```

If you are using the C# for calling the API too, then you could use `HttpClient` where passing the json object of your class a data.

**Edited:** As you are using a third party API, therefore you need to correct the calling.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     //Setting the base address of the server 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sdpondemand.manageengine.com");

    //creating an anonymous object
    var jsonObject = new {
        input_data = new {
             row_count = 100,
             start_index = 101
        }
    };

    //Converting into the content string
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    //waiting for the post request to complete
    var result = await client.PostAsync("app/itdesk/api/v3/requests", content);

    //reading the response string 
    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //Deserialize your string into custom object here
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDTO>(resultContent);
    }
    else
    {
        //Todo: Log the Exception here
        throw new Exception(contentString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> extra : app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={"list_info"{"row_count":100,"start_index":101}}
>   extra1:app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={"list_Info":{"row_count":100,"start_index":101}}

messed up the list info

> extra : app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={"list_info"{"row_count":100,"start_index":101}}
>   extra1:app/itdesk/api/v3/requests?input_data={"list_info":{"row_count":100,"start_index":101}}

[shrug emoji]

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments to this to clear up confusion. ManageEngine Service Desk Plus API is not a properly/typically implemented API. Basically you have to URL encode JSON and pass it in either the URL as a param or in the form as a application/x-www-form-urlencoded

example:

json:

```json
{
  "request": {
    "subject": "testing subject",
    "description": "I am a test. Delete me.",
    "requester": {
      "id": "4817"
    },
    "subcategory": {
      "name": "Errors/Problems Using SalesForce",
      "id": "2406"
    },
    "category": {
      "name": "SalesForce",
      "id": "608"
    }
  }
}
```

becomes:

`input_data='%7B%0A++%22request%22%3A+%7B%0A++++%22subject%22%3A+%22testing+subject%22%2C%0A++++%22description%22%3A+%22I+am+a+test.+Delete+me.%22%2C%0A++++%22requester%22%3A+%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A+%224817%22%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++%22subcategory%22%3A+%7B%0A++++%22name%22%3A+%22Errors%2FProblems+Using+SalesForce%22%2C%0A++++%22id%22%3A+%222406%22%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++%22category%22%3A+%7B%0A++++%22name%22%3A+%22SalesForce%22%2C%0A++++%22id%22%3A+%22608%22%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%0A%7D'`